# NVCC and Boost 1.60 error: identifier "__float128" is undefined

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, caffe

I am trying to compile `caffe` from BVLC (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) but I run into a peculiar error:

```
NVCC src/caffe/util/math_functions.cu
/usr/local/boost/config/suffix.hpp(510): error: identifier "__float128" is undefined
```

It appears to be that when running nvcc on `boost` it is complaining about the `__float128` type.

I googled around and found a [devtalk.nvidia forum post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/696537/cuda6-and-quad-precision-float128-on-host/) but I do not really understand how to solve this issue.

I even opened [a github issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3578) but have not as of yet gotten a reply.

I am using nvcc-6.5 boost 1.60 with gcc-4.8.4 on Debian 8 (I manually installed boost) and the offending line seems to be at line #510:

```
 506 // same again for __float128:                                                                                                          
 507 #if defined(BOOST_HAS_FLOAT128) && defined(__cplusplus)                                                                                
 508 namespace boost {                                                                                                                      
 509 #  ifdef __GNUC__                                                                                                                      
 510    __extension__ typedef __float128 float128_type;                                                                                     
 511 #  else                                                                                                                                
 512    typedef __float128 float128_type;                                                                                                   
 513 #  endif                                                                                                                               
 514 }                                                                                                                                      
 515 #endif
```

A [similar issue in fftw3](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/issues/18) seems to suggest that `nvcc` self-identifies as `__GNUC__` thereby creating he problem?

Is there some work-around for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to a [bug report for boost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11852) this is actually a problem of boost 1.60.

You have several options:

- in the link it is mentioned that `nvcc` (from CUDA 7.5) can deal with `__float128` if you use `-std=c++11`. You need to check if that is an option for `caffee`.
- you might try downgrading boost to 1.59 (the problematic line was introduced with 1.60).
- apply the patch that is mentioned in the link.

Comment: You sire are a life saver!!! I ended up patching it, seemed like the best thing to do. Tons of thanks!!!

Comment: I needed to patch also the 1.55 boost, so I don't think the problem is new.

Comment: @havogt my bad, I have two versions - 1.55 and 1.60; and I only patched the 1.60 (line 156 in config/compiler/gcc.hpp), the other version I got from the repo, but I am using that, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Building and installing boost 1.61 solved the problem.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).